# different output when the script is executed manually and cron job

Tags: shell-script, cron

The script below enters the if loop only if the size of the array is zero ..
When the script is executed manually , the script gives the correct output..
But when I run the same script using cronjob. By default it is executing the else loop.

```
printf "%s\n" "${var[@]}"
if [ ${#var[@]} == 0 ];then
   echo "empty"
   #mailx -s "ALL RUNNING" e.nolan.mit@mobily.com.sa < /apps/lp/Start_Services/running.txt
else
   echo "else part"
   printf "%s\n" "${var[@]}" > filename.txt
   mailx -r scm.admin@mobily.com.sa  -s "RHINE1  10.14.11.77 LOYALTY SERVER" e.nolan.mit@mobily.com.sa < /apps/lp/Start_Services/scm/filename.txt
   echo "I am here"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a cron job, usually is a best practice to specify the full path for files. Most likely the problem is here:

```
printf "%s\n" "${var[@]}" > filename.txt
```

If you try redirecting the output to /apps/lp/Start_Services/scm/filename.txt, it's likely that you'll get the proper output.

Comment: printf "%s\n" "${var[@]}"
 if [ ${#var[@]} == 0 ];then
echo "empty"
echo "I am in if loop `date` " > ifloop.txt
mailx  -r scm.admin@mobily.com.sa -s "ALL RUNNING" e.nolan.mit@mobily.com.sa <  /apps/lp/Start_Services/running.txt
else
echo "else part"
echo "I AM IN Else loop `date` "  > elsepart.txt
printf "%s\n" "${var[@]}" > /apps/lp/Start_Services/scm/filenameC.txt
mailx -r scm.admin@mobily.com.sa  -s "RHINE1  10.14.11.77 LOYALTY SERVER" e.nolan.mit@mobily.com.sa < /apps/lp/Start_Services/scm/filenameC.txt
echo "I am here"
fi

Comment: I have changed according to the above comment but still the cronjob is taking the last 3 values of the array and entering the else loop...

Comment: we have assigned values to the array only if it enters the if loop for ex

Comment: ps -ef|grep LPMREDSUP |grep -v grep
     if [ $? -ne 0 ]
       then
        var[32]="process LPMREDSUP not running"
     fi

echo "*************************************"
echo ""

ps -ef|grep LPAPDELPT | grep -v grep
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
       then
             var[33]="process LPAPDELPT not running "

Comment: if the service is running then the value of the array is empty...

Comment: if ts empty then the  mail subject should be "ALL RUNNING"...... But now thought the services are running else part is triggered.....